# Does ansible win_chocolatey module support retries?

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-playbook

Has anyone ever seen **retries** work on an ansible win_chocolatey task?

The follow seems to fail on the first attempt with no retries and I'm getting timeouts at the ansible level while choco attempts to install a package.

```
- name: Install Chocolatey
  win_chocolatey:
    name: a_package
    env: choco
  retries: 3
```

Have you successfully used **retries** with win_chocolatey tasks?

**Possible Solution**
Using Henrik's suggestion and a block, I have retries plus a rescue/catch operation to fetch the choco log in case of errors after retries

```
- name: install applications
  block:
  - win_chocolatey:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      source:  "{{ choco_artifactory_source }}"
    register: result
    until: result.rc == 0
    retries: 3
    with_items:
      - wget
      - curl
  rescue:
  - fetch:
      src: "{{ choco_log }}"
      dest: "{{ agent_log_dir }}"
      flat: yes
```

Comment: what's the with_items stanza's purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `until` parameter defined, thus

> If the `until` parameter isn’t defined, the value for the `retries` parameter is forced to `1`.

applies.

See the [documentation for do-until loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops) for more information.